# Covariance of random variables with a constraint

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance, correlation

Solving this question will (hopefully) also solve the confusion I have in [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564061/how-can-i-simulate-uncertainty-propagation).

I have two random Gaussian variables $A$ and $B$ with $\mu_A, \mu_B$ and $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$ respectively.

I have the constraint that $Z=AB^3$ is Gaussian with $\mu_Z$ and $\sigma_Z$. How can I determine the $\text{Cov}\left(A,B\right)$?

My end goal is to run a simulation that uses these variables that satisfy the constraint above. I **think** that I need to know the covariance between $A$ and $B$ in order to correctly generate them and satisfy all the above conditions.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to move forward?

Comment: It seems you need to rethink your strategy. It is not at all clear whether it is even possible to find a joint distribution of $(A,B)$ such that $Z$ is Gaussian. And if it does, the dependency between $A$ and $B$ may be so constrained (read: weird, non-Gaussian) that the covariance will not help at all.

Comment: Hmm ignoring the "weird, non-Gaussian", how can I get the Covariance? Maybe it will not help with my end goal of running a simulation, but it could help me understand a bit what is going on.

Comment: Are you sure that $A$ and $B$ need to be Gaussian? If they were log-normal, the problem would be more natural!